# Loading object by Deserializing existing xml

Tags: xml, vb.net, deserialization

I am attempting to load a class via deserialization.  I have an XML file and its XSD file and I have generated the C# classes with the XSD.EXE program.  I have converted code found on the internet to VB.  The application compiles OK but crashes before reaching the new code.  When I remove the loading code, the application runs normally.  The error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There was an error reflecting type 'ActuarialStuff.TablesSOA'.

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOATables>
<XTbML>
</XTbML>
.
.
.
<XTbML>
</XTbML>
<SOATables>
```

Target Object:

```
<System.Serializable>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("SOATables")>
Public Class TablesSOA
    <XmlArray("SOATables")>
    <XmlArrayItem("XTbML", GetType(XTbML))>
    Public Property TabSOA() As XTbML
End Class
```

Loading code:

```
    Dim path As String = "O:\OneDrive\Documents\Actuarial Stuff\SOATables\SOA.XML"
    Dim tSOA As TablesSOA
    Dim ser As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(TablesSOA))
    Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(path)
        tSOA = CType(ser.Deserialize(reader), TablesSOA)
    End Using
```

Thanks,

Keith

Comment: What is the `XTbML` object? Is it serializable?

Comment: What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception, if any?  The inner exception probably explains the problem.  The most likely cause is that `XTbML` lacks a public parameterless constructor; it must have one to be deserialized with `XmlSerializer`.  Otherwise, can [edit] your question to provide a full [mcve]?